# "ruby -v" no longer returning current version

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rvm

In the process of trying to upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3, I think I broke something. I believe I have Ruby 1.9.3 successfully installed. However, now when I type `ruby -v` into terminal, I'm not getting any messages. Here's the sample output:

```
rish-macbookair:~ rish$ ruby -v
rish-macbookair:~ rish$
```

One of the last things I did was install the "Command Line Tools" in XCode because I was getting a "missing libraries" error.

Any ideas on what might have happened, or where to start?

**Edit: upon trying to reinstall 1.9.3, I get this:**

```
rish-macbookair:~ rish$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3
/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327 has already been removed.
Removing /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327...
https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.bz2 - #configure
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #download
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extract
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #validate
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #setup
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
Saving wrappers to '/usr/local/rvm/bin'.
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #importing default gemsets (/usr/local/rvm/gemsets/), this may take time ...
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p327 pristine.
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p327@global pristine.
rish-macbookair:~ rish$
```

I have tried reinstalling RVM as well, but I'm back in the same place

Comment: What's the output of `which ruby`?

Comment: /Users/rish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby

Comment: Looks like ruby 1.9.3 to me `:)` How about `irb -v`?

Comment: The output is:

/Users/rish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/irb: line 6: /Users/rish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby: Undefined error: 0

When I'm running ruby programs, I'm no longer getting any output messages. Do you know what that could be?

Comment: Sounds like your ruby installation is hosed. Try reinstalling. Sorry, I know that's not very helpful, but it sounds like something on your system is fundamentally wonky.

Comment: This is what I get when reinstalling:
/Users/rish/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327 has already been removed.
Removing /Users/rish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327...
https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.bz2 - #configure
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #download
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extract
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #validate
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #setup
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
Saving wrappers to '/Users/rish/.rvm/bin'.
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #importing default gemsets (/Users/rish/.rvm/gemsets/), this may take time ...
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p327 pristine.
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p327@global pristine

Comment: @rishim3 It's easier to read the error message when it's added as an edit to the question, rather than pasted into a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using old version of rvm, try:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3
```